# Divide Zero error when calculating Sales % in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting the following error message:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Divide by zero error encountered.

I've seen some posts about using `IFNULL` which I have tried.
For example:

```
,Case when a.DiscountReasonCode = 'RL' then IFNULL(((a.ORIGINALRETAIL-a.RetOne) / (a.ORIGINALRETAIL) * 100),0) end as [PctSB]
```

But this returns the following error:

> 'IFNULL' is not a recognized built-in function name.

What I'm doing is trying to calculate the proper sales percent and then find and compare it to what is already in the table to find errors or missing Sales %'s.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
a.packnum
,a.description
,a.CatID
,a.PctSavings
,Case when a.DiscountReasonCode = 'RL' then (a.ORIGINALRETAIL-a.RetOne) / (a.ORIGINALRETAIL) * 100 
end as [PctSB]

FROM PIC704Current a Join CatalogInfo b ON (a.CatID = b.Catalog) and (a.Year = b.MailYear)

WHERE
b.MediaId in('CAT Catalog','SCAT Sale Catalog','SSTF Sale Statement Stuff','STUF Statement 
Stuffer','PKG Package Insert','SPKG Sale Pkg Insert')
and a.DiscountReasonCode = 'RL'
and a.year >='2020'
and (Case when a.PctSavings <> (a.ORIGINALRETAIL-a.RetOne)/a.ORIGINALRETAIL*100 then 'False' else 
'True' END) = 'False'
```

Thanks

Comment: https://data-flair.training/blogs/sql-null-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping a divide in a null test will not get rid of the divide by 0 error. Instead, you need to check whether the value being divided by is 0 and return a different value instead. You can do this using [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
IIF(a.ORIGINALRETAIL = 0, 0, 100.0 * (a.ORIGINALRETAIL-a.RetOne) / a.ORIGINALRETAIL)
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone each one of these is a resolution. Honestly the one thing I wasn't thinking. It totally skipped my mind that Original retail may be set to zero thus it wouldn't be divisible and it just didn't register to me till I saw this. Thanks so much for the help everyone!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce` or `isnull` . MySQL uses `ifnull`

```
case 
  when a.DiscountReasonCode = 'RL' then (a.ORIGINALRETAIL-a.RetOne) / 
  NULLIF(a.ORIGINALRETAIL, 0) * 100 
end as [PctSB]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried both Coalesce and isnull but still getting the divide by zero error. I also disabled the where statement to make sure. But same issue.

Comment: @Deke try now.  I have updated my answer. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Divide by zero error encountered.

This error suggests that your denominator is 0 so you can change it to NULL using a case expression.

> 'IFNULL' is not a recognized built-in function name.

In SQL Server , you can use `ISNULL`  or `Coalesce`

```
CASE WHEN a.DiscountReasonCode = 'RL' 
     THEN ISNULL(((a.ORIGINALRETAIL-a.RetOne)/(CASE WHEN a.ORIGINALRETAIL = 0 
                                                    THEN NULL
                                                    ELSE a.ORIGINALRETAIL
                                                    END) * 100),0)
     END AS [PctSB]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the posts you've seen mentioning `IFNULL` might actually have been mentioning `NULLIF`, you just remembered it the wrong way round. One of the typical tricks to avoid a DIV/0 error in sqlserver:

```
some_number / NULLIF(other_number_maybe_zero, 0)
```

If the divisor is 0, it is converted to null, meaning the result is null rather than an error

In standard SQL you can do it too:

```
some_number / CASE WHEN other_number_maybe_zero = 0 THEN NULL ELSE other_number_maybe_zero END
```

It's just a bit more wordy

Answer (score 0):

The logic that you want is provided by `NULLIF()`:

```
(a.ORIGINALRETAIL - a.RetOne) * 100.0 / NULLIF(a.ORIGINALRETAIL, 0)) * 100) as [PctSB]
```

Using the standard SQL function `NULLIF()` is the simplest way to do what you want, and I recommend that you write the logic this way.  It replaces any `0` value with `NULL` -- thereby avoiding the divide-by-zero.